# Loading indicator between two screens GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a button in my home page in GWT. When clicking to this button, the screen is updated with new GWT elements and, without send a RPC call. But between these 2 screens, there is a long time. So I want to make a loading indicator (like a animated gif) for that.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Before trying to workaround your issue, I'd start digging and understand _why_ this is slow. 'cause showing the loading indicator could be as slow as showing the second screen. Also, don't judge performance in DevMode.

Comment: the problem is that block the application around 4 seconds !!!

Comment: But you're saying you don't do RPC (which I understand more broadly as "no communication with a server, waiting for a response"), so **what** blocks for 4 seconds?

Comment: Thank you thomas. The problem doesn't occur in production mode as you say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GWT class PopupPanel has an optional "glass panel" that blocks interaction with the page underneath.

```
final PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel(false, true); // Create a modal dialog box that will not auto-hide
popup.add(new Label("Please wait"));
popup.setGlassEnabled(true); // Enable the glass panel
popup.center(); // Center the popup and make it visible
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have implemented he same. I have attached a loading image before loading the other screen.Below is the code:

```
public class Utility {

private static LoadingDlg dlg=new LoadingDlg(false, true);

public static void showLoading(){
    if(count <= 0){


        dlg.center();
        count = 1;
    }
    else
    count++;

}
public static void hideLoading(){
    if(count <= 1){
        dlg.hide();     
        count = 0;
    }
    else{
    count--;
    }
}

}






public LoadingDlg(boolean autoHide, boolean modal) {
    super(autoHide, modal);
    this.setGlassEnabled(true);
    this.setTitle("Press Esc Key to Hide.");
    this.setGlassStyleName("loadingstyle");     
    FlowPanel hp=new FlowPanel();
    hp.setStyleName("loadingImg");
    this.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(500);
    this.setWidget(hp);

}
```

Css for the same:

```
.loadingstyle{
display: block !important;   
visibility: visible !important;    
z-index: 500 !important;
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30);
```

}

```
   .loadingImg{
background-image:url(images/loadingimage.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display: block; 
height: 24px;
width: 161px;
```

}
.

You have to add a loadingimage.gif  in your images folder and just call showLoading and hideLoading function accordingly.